# Database (or table) of functions obeying symmetry properties of space groups

Tags: crystallography, mathematical-modeling, symmetry, databases, space-groups

I'm looking for a table or database containing mathematical functions that belong to crystallographic space groups by having the same symmetry elements.

Imagine a 2D square planar lattice. It has a 4-fold rotational symmetry as well as 4 reflection directions. The function $f(x,y) = \cos(x) + \cos(y)$ has the same symmetry. What I'm looking for is a database / table which contains such functions for (ideally all) crystallographic space groups (I'm currently most interested in Bi2Se3 and thus the space group #166)

Comment: +1. I love this question, largely because I love databases. I'm looking forward to seeing the answers that arise here.

Comment: I do not know anything about such databases, though my intuition says that's a problem for evolutionary programming. All you need is a carefully prepared set of symmetry operations for your system (symops for the space group of interest and symops for supergroups), and a code for creating/modifying functions and symmetry checking.

Comment: Mika, @IvanChernyshov, I was just looking through a book by Schoenflies from 1891 and found [something that might be interesting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Cxbf.png) in the context of this conversation.